# Linear Algebra, Matrix Multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Find matrix of a given linear operator in given new bases using matrix multiplication only:
>   $$L = \langle e_1,e_2,e_3 \rangle, M =\langle g1,g2 \rangle \\[6pt]
> \begin{cases}f(e1) = g1 −2g2 \\ f(e2) = g1 +g2 \\ f(e3) = 2g1 +3g2\end{cases} \\[10pt]
> e ̃1 =2e1 −e3, e ̃2 =e2 +e3, e ̃3 =e1 −e2, g ̃1 =g1 +2g2, g ̃2 =2g1 −g2$$

Any help is appreciated please!

Comment: I edited a little bit of MathJax into your question for you to show you how it's done.  Do you have any thoughts on the exercise yourself?  If so, edit them into the question as well.

Comment: Here's my hint:  You'll want to change the bases of the domain and codomain so once you find your transition matrices, the formula for change of bases is given by $$[f]_{\tilde M \leftarrow \tilde L} = [I_2]_{\tilde M \leftarrow M} [f]_{M \leftarrow L} [I_3]_{L\leftarrow \tilde L}$$